# Informix 11.50 over onsoctcp, dbaccess as root, not trusted

Tags: informix

I have two SLES 11 servers. One has my Informix 11.50.FC6 database. I installed the IDS engine on my other server so I could get dbaccess. I have entries in /etc/hosts.equiv and I can use dbaccess as a normal non-root user, but when I try to run dbaccess as root, I get the following error in my Informix log:

```
Client host or user root@app is not trusted by the server.
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the Host in your .rhosts file. Don't forget to set proper permissions on that file (600)